# Rebooted host machine from inside VM, should I report this issue and where to report?

Tags: virtualization

Excuse my ignorance as I don't work in infosec.

I ran `reboot` inside a linux virtual machine using VirtualBox on Mac and it rebooted my host machine. I am trying to reproduce the problem but haven't gotten it right just yet.

If I am able to reproduce the issue, should I report it and who should I report it to?

Comment: Are you sure when you ran `reboot` inside the VM, you were not connected via SSH to the host machine? Wouldn't be the first time something like that has happened.

Comment: A reboot of the Guest-VM should not cause a reboot of the host. If you've found a bug in Virtualbox please use their [Bugtracker](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker) to report it.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you accidentally ran `reboot` on your host machine instead of the VM. Double-check this first.